# Hudson Configuration for war deployment on Tomcat server with SVN

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I need to configure Hudson using SVN and ANT . I need to deploy the war file at my server. Please navigate to the proper help. As I could not find any proper help for this. Do I need to use any plug-in? Or I can do with ANT script? Please suggest a way.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new **free-style software project** job.
- **Configure** that job.
- Under **Source Code Management** section, select **Subversion** and configure your repositories and local workspace
- Under **Build** section, select **Add build step** and select **Invoke Ant**
- If your SVN checkout has `build.xml` in the root with default target, you don't need anything else. Else configure the Ant targets and the location of the build file
- (Optional) Archive the artifacts of the build with **Archive the artifacts** under **Post-build Actions**, in your case probably `**/*.war`
- Use **[Deploy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin)** to publish the war file to remote server.